# Does Windows XP support the SSD trim command?

Tags: windows-xp, ssd

I am thinking about purchasing an SSD to speed up my Windows XP system. I heard that the TRIM command is important to maintaining the SSD performance over the long run. So is getting an SSD for Windows XP a good idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, Windows XP does not support the TRIM command by itself, although it appears OCZ has [released firmware](http://www.ocztechnology.com/aboutocz/news/155) to give XP support for idle garbage collection for some of their SSDs. Idle garbage collection is not the same as TRIM and will not perform as well, but it works similarly. So far I believe the Vertex and Summit series have this capability.

Answer (score 8):

Intel offers Trim support for XP and Vista....see their site here:
http://www.intel.com/design/flash/nand/value/overview.htm?2515521749

Read about- "Intel® SSD Toolbox with Intel® SSD Optimizer"

Excerpt from link above-

"..The Intel SSD Optimizer also works with Microsoft Windows Vista* and XP* operating systems as well."

Comment: Yes, but that it not the same thing. TRIM means that OS and SSD work together. The SSD Toolbox is a program that you must run from time to time to clean the empty space.

Comment: It seems like Intel SSD Toolbox only does the useful stuff on their own drives.  :(